# How to get progress of uploading file with php 5.3 (CodeIgniter)?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have Ajax upload form which works normal, but I want to create and progress bar with percentige of uploading process.
Is there way to get percentege only with JS, how to get that value with PHP ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP >= 5.4, then you can use [session.upload_progress](http://php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php)

Since you've stated you're using PHP 5.3, then the answer is no, not with pure PHP. You'd have to end up using a Flash-based solution or find something else to rely on.

Comment: I am using PHP 5.3